# LibreOffice Impress: script to download images from file

Tags: linux, command-line, script, images, libreoffice-impress

I would like to export all images contained in slideshow files with command-line instructions.

I am aware that I could convert the files into PDF documents and then use **pdfmod** to export the images. In that case, though, I have noted that the images that had been rotated in the slideshow also maintain that rotation in the exported image.

The aim would be to export images that are as close as possible to the originals placed in the slideshow.

Which programs and instruction would you suggest to perform this task efficiently and accurately? Thanks for thinking along.

Working with Linux Ubuntu 14.04 and LibreOffice 3.5.7.2.

Answer (score 1):

From my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34142392/5100564):

> You can get all the images by unzipping the .odp file and looking in the resulting Pictures subdirectory.

An example of using the `unzip` command line utility is at: https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=36628.